# Angular 2 - Pass parameters to Route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a `<a>` tag like below,

```
<a [routerLink]="[/Person']">Person</a>
```

So I want to pass the `person.id` to this `/Person` router. How can I pass it & handle it on `@RouteConfig` like `params` in Angular 1

Comment: There is no `@RouteConfig`. What Angular2 version are you using?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Pass** to router link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Person', person.id]">Person</a>
```

**Handle** in component:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
   (params: Params) => {
      this.id = params['id']; 
   }
);
```

*Second way:*

```
this.route.params.forEach(
   (params: Params) => {
       this.id = params['id'];
   }
);
```

In this example you have to inject `ActivatedRoute` (*e.g as route property*) like that:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

If you subscribe - it is important to unsubscribe `Observable` to prevent **memory leaks**.

Full example:

```
export class SimpleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private id: number;
    private route$: Subscription;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route$ = this.route.params.subscribe(
            (params: Params) => {
                this.id = +params['id']; // cast to number
            }
        );
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.route$) this.route$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**Config**:

```
export const routes = [
    ...
    { path : 'Person/:id', component : ...},
    ...
];
```

Also, `@RouteConfig` is **deprecated**.

Comment: Good answer, couple of comments. First, you're missing the opening single-quote in the `'/Person'`.
Second, according to [Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters), you can access the parameters also like this:
`ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
     let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
   });`

Finally, if you're using subscribe, remember to unsubscribe on the ngOnDestroy.

Comment: Thanks for your attention about the single quote - I edited post. About unsubscribe - this is obvious. It is important to do it to prevent memory leaks. I will add it to answer :)

Comment: **Handle in component:**

`this.route.params.subscribe(
   (params : Params) => {
      this.id = params["id"]; 
   }
);`       this thing, it will be writtern in that class where the user will be navigated, that is, in its ngOnInit() method. Right?

Comment: Also, where can i find this **Subscription** class. It is throwing error as cannot find..

Answer (score 4):

You can pass it like

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Person', propertyWithId]">Person</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, directive `[routerLink]` didn't work for me. So, I had to do it programmatically.

Component template:

```
<a (click)="goToEdit(person.id)" >Edit</a>
```

Component Class:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class PersonComponent{

    constructor(private _route: Router){ }

    goToEdit(id){
        this._route.navigate(['Person/' + id]);
    }

}
```