# Angular : how to send params with routing path?

Tags: angular, routes

Suppose that I have three different API's that describe categories (Cars, Color, Food). In `routerLink` I use this  `routerLink="/{{element.name}}"` and in my module I use:

```
 path: ':id',
 component: ListComponent
```

Now, when I route it becomes like this: `localhost:4200/red`, which is fine for me, but how can I send something unique with this URL to make sure that the element is color and handle it somewhere in my code?

Comment: Well, pass the category and its value: /colors/red, or /cars/ford, or /food/bread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Pass parameters to Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045504/angular-2-pass-parameters-to-route)

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  //...
  { path: 'colors/:color', component: ColorsComponent },
  //...
];
```

You can use these routes like this in your template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/colors', 'red']">Something</a>
```

Or:

```
goToRed() {
  this.router.navigate(['/colors', 'red']);
}
```

Of course `'red'` can be a variable too.
And you can subscribe to this parameter in your component's `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.color = params['color'];
       //You can check the color here.
    });
  }
```

You can use this method for the Cars and Foods too.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to pass **aditional 'parameters'**. You can try this:

```
{
    path: 'colors/:color',
    component: ColorComponent,
    data: {someValue: 123}
}
```

In your component, you can use `this.route.data` to access it. The URL will still be look like this: `localhost:4200/colors/red` for example.

Comment: Perfect! but how can I make my url like this `localhost:4200/red` but in my function I want to send the `id` not the name, so that I need to show the user 'red' word but actually the value is `id`

Comment: In my code's case the URL will look like this (for example): `localhost:4200/colors/red`, and the params['color'] will have the value 'red' as a string.

Comment: Do you want to send an additional parameter to the component without showing it in the URL?

Comment: Yes for example if I have `localhost:4200/red/123` I want the url shown by user like this  `localhost:4200/red` but in my function I will ignore the car and handle the id 123.

Comment: Great, but where can I pass the 123 from my html to the aditional parameters?

Comment: There are no good solution for this, I think. Maybe you can create a route with `/colors/red/123` and immediately redirect it to `colors/red`, but it's not the best. You have to have every information in your URL that you need in your code. Alternatively, you can use a service to store the `123` value for you, but that is in your Typescript code and not in your HTML.