# How can i use templateUrl more than one in angular 2 final

Tags: c#, angular, components

```
@Component({
selector: 'food-form',
templateUrl : './app/form.html',
templateUrl : './app/form2.html'        
})
```

can i use it or not ?  I wanna split my template because it's similar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you cannot use `templateUrl` more than once in a component because of Javascript object literal concept, what you have to do in your case is you need to create another component which includes shared form and then you need to create component1 and component2 and in both components, need to add shared-form directive that you have created. Shared from needs to have a service as well to be able to communicate with both components.

In other words, It would be like this

```
@Component({
selector: 'shared-form',
templateUrl : './app/shared-form.html',     
})

@Component({
selector: 'food-form',
templateUrl : './app/form.html',
})


@Component({
selector: 'food-form2',
templateUrl : './app/form2.html',
})
```

and then in both template `form2.html` and `form1.html`  you are able to use

```
<shared-form></shared-form>
```

which enables you to have one shared form between two views.

Note: if logics in shared form should be used in both components then you need to have a middle service to pass different value between components. There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981545/passing-value-between-two-angular2-component-typescript-files/39982664#39982664).

This could be applied to different things what you need to keep in mind is which part of your code should be reusable and then make that a component.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use it because..

```
[ts] An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.
```

You can use `template`. Angular2 Typescript allows to write multi-line templates by using ` characters to enquote them.

Comment: Can i use  templateUrl  and template ?

Comment: If you use both together then only `template` data will display on the page